# Generar un reloj para reproducir las señales horarias

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, y me gustaría añadir a mi proyecto las señales horarias de la radio, ya sabéis, cuando suena el pitido:

Beep, beep, beep, beep , beep , beeeeeeeeeeeep;

Se generar el código de la cuenta atrás y los Beep, lo que no sé, es como generar el reloj para que haga una vuelta del bucle cada segundo, y tampoco como generar un solo tono largo en la misma frecuencia que el que se ofrece por defecto.

He probado con:

```
Console.Beep(25000, 2000);
```

pero ni la frecuencia es la misma, y me sale son sonido largo, pues me reproduce varios pitidos por el tiempo indicado, pero no uno solo.

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
    if ((i < 5) && (i > 0)){
        Console.Beep();
    }
    else if (i == 0){
        Console.Beep(); //No sé como generar un solo Beep largo
    }
}
```

Alguien me podría asesorar ?

EDITADO:

He creado éste método, no se si podrá funcionar, pero no puedo saberlo hasta que falten unos minutos para en punto.

```
private void lblReloj_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:54")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:55")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:56")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:57")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:58")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:59")
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:00")
        {
            Console.Beep(20000, 800);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para generar el reloj podría ayudarte, lamentablemente, el Beep no lo controlo

A ver si te sirve:

```
//en el load del formulario
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ponemos el cambio cada segundo.  
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

        // Iniciamos el reloj
        timer.Start();

        //cambiamos el texto del botón a "Stop" ahora tenemos el reloj funcionando
        btnReloj.Text = "Stop";
        btnReloj.Click += new EventHandler(btnReloj_Click);
    }
```

Luego creas los siguientes métodos:

```
//método asociado a incluir un Timer en tu formulario
private void Timer_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Capturamos la hora y la escribimos en el label, yo lo llamo Reloj.  
        lblReloj.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        //Podemos capturar la fecha y escribirla en el label que yo llamo fecha
        lblFecha.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    }

    //En un botón, por ejemplo llamado btnReloj
    private void btnReloj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Si el texto del botón es "Stop"
        if (btnReloj.Text == "Stop")
        {
            //Cambiamos el texto a "Star" tenemos el reloj parado
            btnReloj.Text = "Start";
            //paramos el reloj
            timer.Stop();
        }
        //si el texto del botón no está en "Stop" estará en "Start"
        else
        {
            //Cambiamos el texto del botón a "Stop" tenemos el reloj funcionando
            btnReloj.Text = "Stop";
            //ponemos el reloj en marcha
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que guay, funciona muy bien, es un reloj digital. He modificado mi pregunta y añadido un nuevo método, pero no se si funcionará hasta que llegue una hora en punto. Muchas gracias. Me queda el tema del Beep. Cambiaré me pregunta y generaré un nueva preguntando sobre el Beep.